# Cómo mantener la sesión iniciada utilizando FireBase en web

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

estoy realizando una aplicación utilizando básicamente html, js y firebase. ya tengo realizadas las cuestiones del Auth y dependiendo el tipo de usuario es el html que se abre a continuación ¿como hacer que la sesión ya iniciada siga iniciada con el mismo usuario en el siguiente html? (ya probé utilizando el js que contiene el apikey que me proporciona firebase)

Answer (score 1):

De manera predeterminada la sesión queda abierta (ya que se almacena en LocalStorage), entonces solo puedes verificarlo con la siguiente instrucción:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // usuario está logueado.
  } else {
    // usuario NO está logueado.
  }
});
```

Referencia: ("Obtén el usuario con sesión activa") 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users?hl=es-419

Answer (score -1):

Joder tío, lo que puedes realizar es revisar la documentación que te ofrece Firebase, para ser específicos en la siguiente URL que te anexo:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence?hl=es-419

Saludos chaval...

Comment: si sos gilipollas, te he dicho que ya lo he hecho tio! grathias de todas formas